# Eclipse Browser not showing back/front with Plug-in Development

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to populate a url in eclipse browser through plug-in development, but I am not getting back/fw button as it normally shows in the browser of eclipse.
My code snippet looks -

```
     Browser browser = new Browser(parent, 0);
   browser.setUrl("http://www.google.com"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below API

```
org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbench.getBrowserSupport().createBrowser(null).openURL
```